# If neutronium existed out there, are we capable of observing it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, observables, neutrons

I know that theoretically, neutronium cannot exist. However, no work was done until now even looking for neutronim around us. So my question is that, if neutronium actually existed with some minimum mass number (above 2, excluding the observed unbound dineutron in 2012), can we observe them?

They don't interact with optical light, as the minimum photon energy to excite surface neutrons should be very high, and they are not charged! So how we can proof our theoretical look for neutronium?

My question is about how can we roof our theoretical look for neutronium?

Comment: Neutrons have a nonzero magnetic moment, they do interact with photons, it's just a very small effect.